# Partial part of the buttons were truncated in the suggested edit review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, suggested-edits

There is an alignment issue in the suggested edit's **rendered output** and **markdown** buttons in Meta Stack Exchange, the top part of the buttons are truncated. [Sample suggested edit](/review/suggested-edits/51060).

Screenshot from MSE:

[image: Review button alignment issue]

Screenshot from Stack Overflow:

[image: From SO]

**Configurations:**

Zoom: 100%
Mozilla Firefox: 54.0b13 (32-bit)
Google Chrome: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @AaronShekey Can you please add the status-completed tag, after the build deployed to live.

Comment: It's tougher to do that, since our engineers decide when deploys happen. We don't have a good way of monitoring when our changes go live, and frankly, we're all a little busy :)